# Converted value of a int variable to string and assigning it to a new variable is becomes zero

Tags: python, string

I've written a python module which gets the count of records available in a file and stores it into a variable. Later I need this value to be converted to string and compare with a user supplied value. Surprisingly, the int converted to string using python str() function is becoming zero. Could someone let me know how to resolve this problem? Below is the code and output,

```
def compareFileCount(self, step, path, exp):
    dirpath = path
    teststep = step
    value = exp
    command = "wc -l <"+" "+dirpath
    operation = os.system(command)
    print operation
    operation1=str(operation)
    print "value of operation1 = "+operation1
    if operation1 == value:
            print "File record count "+operation1+" is equal to expected value of - "+value+". Test Step Passed for -"+teststep
            self.logstatus(teststep, "PASSED")
    else:
            print "File record count "+operation1+" is not equal to expected value of - "+value+". Test Step Failed for -"+teststep
            self.logstatus(teststep, "FAILED")
```

When called the above method with below value,

```
os.compareFileCount("teststpe1", "/data/automation/202585_ForkJoin/testfiles/hvac_feed1.csv", "4")
```

## Output

```
4
0
value of operation1 = 0
File record count 0 is not equal to expected value of - 4. Test Step Failed for -teststpe1
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. The result of `os.system` is already 0, as that is the exit code of the `wc` command.

Comment: Ideally, the variable "operation" is holding the output of command os.system(wc -l < /data/automation/202585_ForkJoin/testfiles/hvac_feed1.csv) which is "4". But when I convert this to string using str() and assign it to operation1, the value printed later from "operation1" is "0". Ideally it should contain '4' which is not being done.

Comment: But it doesn't contain that. It contains the exit code of the command, as your output demonstrates. It was never 4, it was always 0.

Comment: When I print the value of "operation" it's clearly shown the record count of "4". Why not this being assigned to "operation1" variable?

Comment: No it does not. It clearly shows the output 0.

Answer (score 2):

On Unix, the return value of os.system is the exit status of the process, so 0 means the process exited without errors. You should use something like the example below:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
tmp = proc.stdout.read()
```